# How to capture frames from webcam in Windows Service with C#?

Tags: windows-services, webcam

Is it a way to capture video frames from webcam in Windows Service? WIA always need a parent handler which can only be used in Windows client with user interface.

I need to write a windows service to process webcam frames but I don't know how to achieve this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Peter